# Get Coding Book - understanding variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just getting into the world of programming and maybe I'm jumping the gun a little by asking to quickly, but I didn't understand something from a book I'm reading. Why do I need to create a variable for the element password box, wouldn't the variable hold the value of what's typed into it. ~ sorry :c

```
function checkPassword() {
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
    var passwordGuessed = password.value;

    if(passwordGuessed == "Ernest300") {
        return true;
    }

    alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @NitinDhomse No it is not. No need for an else if you have a return

Comment: Not very clear what you're asking. Do you expect `password` to already hold the value of the password?

Comment: Well the book explained it this way, the else statement wouldn't be needed because the return statement would stop the function.

Comment: You do not need to create a separate var unless you need it later. For example: `var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
    var passwordGuessed = password.value; ...alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!"); password .focus();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("passwordBox")` returns an HTML element object, which contains way more than just the value typed into the input. If you wanted to, you could do with just one variable assignment like this: `var passwordGuessed = document.getElementById("passwordBox").value;` but most would agree that two lines are more readable, plus you might want to check something else from the element object (whether it was found at all etc.) before accessing the value.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks teukkam.. really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a separate var unless you need it later. For example:

```
function checkPassword() {
  var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox"); // gets the HTML object
  var passwordGuessed = password.value;  // gets the value of it

  if(passwordGuessed == "Ernest300") {
    return true;
  }
  alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!"); 
  password .focus(); // reuse the var
}
```

vs

```
function checkPassword() {
    var password = document.getElementById("passwordBox").value;
    if (password == "Ernest300") {
        return true;
    }

    alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!");
    return false;
}
```

or even shorter - however it is always prudent to use a var in case you want to test the validity:

```
function checkPassword() {
    if(document.getElementById("passwordBox").value == "Ernest300") {
        return true;
    }

    alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, that's very helpful I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

The variable does not hold the value of what's typed in the password box, but holds a reference to the password box HTML element itself. You can get the value of what's typed in the password box by accessing the element's `value` property.

The variables here make the code easier to read, but you don't really *need* them. The entire snippet could be rewritten as:

```
function checkPassword() {
    if(document.getElementById("passwordBox").value == "Ernest300") {
        return true;
    }

    alert("I'm sorry, your login credentials were incorrect buddy!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That makes things a lot clearer, thank you ever so much Robby - I kind of thought of it like that so I felt like I was missing something!